# Does the sequence $a_n=\cos(n\pi/2)$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the  sequence $a_n=\cos(n\pi/2)$ converge or diverge?

Comment: Can you write the first few values of this sequence?  Perhaps you'll see a pattern.

Answer (score 5):

It's divergent, since the subsequences $a_{4n} = \cos(2n\pi) = 1$ and $a_{4n+2} = \cos((2n+1)\pi) = -1$ have distinct limits.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: The sequence (starting with $n=0$) is
$$1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,\ldots$$
Does this sequence converge to some limit? Does it diverge to infinity?